# Strange one-way binding in Angular-UI Modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am running into a strange one way binding behavior within a Angular-UI-Bootstrap Modal.

Inside a modal html, two day data binding seems to work fine but the scope variable model at the controller does not update for some reason.

If, however, the scope variable is an object, then the two way binding seems to propagate to the controller.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Anyway to fix it?

I have made a plunker to demonstrate the problem.

[One way binding in Modal problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/p8e3mmtdC7QfHQSImHPb?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the most common problem I see people having with angular; **nested scopes**. Have a look at the following resource: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

This essentially boils down to the following. If you attempt to access `$scope.someVal`, angular will search up the parent chain looking for `someVal`, and if found will return it to you. If you try and change `someVal`, it will simply create a new `someVal` to the current scope.

If however you attempt to access `$scope.someObj.someVal`, reading acts the same way. Except this time if you try to change `someVal`, it will change the value inside `someObj`, no matter which scope is commanding the update.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I am sure the problem is related to the nested scope problem even though I have tried with different names, linking and not linking to the parent scope using the scope option parameter.  Nothing seems to make a difference.  I guess I just have to create an object if I want to read the changed model value from the modal controller.