# How can I set the value of a form to pristine from a home controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have this situation:

```
<body ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
   <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
       <form name="mainForm" >
  <button type"button" ng-click="mp1()">Make Pristine 1</button>
  <button type"button" ng-click="mp2()">Make Pristine 2</button>
```

This works in MainCtrl:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mp2 = function() {
    $scope.mainForm.$setPristine();
  }
});
```

This doesn't work in HomeCtrl:

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mp1 = function() {
    $scope.mainForm.$setPristine();
  }
});
```

Here's a plunkr that show the problem:  [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Xqm5NHpmxxOjuqa3V6V?p=preview)

What I am trying to do is to get the validity checks and the ability to set pristine both working. I tried different combinations of using  and ngForm, setting the form as an object in the outer scope etc.  Still can't get it all to work for both. Note that I really need to do the $setPristine in the HomeCtrl as there are different MainCtrl's and I don't want to reimplement the code a lot of times.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115470/strange-one-way-binding-in-angular-ui-modal/22115530#22115530

Comment: Hello Matt, I realize the problem is with scopes but I was able to solve this for the validity checks by declaring var xxform = {} in the outer controller  However I can't get this to work with $setPristine. That's my big problem.

Answer (score 5):

You need to solve the nested scope issue by wrapping the form object in a container:

```
<form name="cont.mainForm">
```

Then setup the `cont` object in you highest level controller

```
$scope.cont = {};
```

Then use the main form similarly to what you have in your controllers:

```
$scope.cont.mainForm.$setPristine();
```

Here is an updated plunk for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/VKY7PlwZgUuVN6jfpAG8?p=preview

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I did read the links but I was not aware that I could do this: name="cont.mainForm"  I thought it would just take a simple name. I will check this in my application now.